# Ajax not returning any <table> atributes

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

This is rather weird, and rather complicated, im going to try to explain it as best as i can. im making a calendar by hand, plan on open sourcing it etc. Im currently going for the look and feel of google calendar, as they seem to be the best, however i do plan on one upping it + open source. Everything is running flawlessly except when i click previous month, in order to view previous month, then ajax query is ran, the php returns the new calendar, but when it renders it renders without the **ANY** `<table>` elements other than that havent hit a snag yet any ideas? heres some code/images:

html:

```
//function to use xml
function xml(){
 //need to set up xml to run php for query
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
   {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
     document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
}

//function to select the previous month
function previousMonth(str){
//since this is the previous month we need to take month -1
var month = str - 1;
 //if it is already 1.. then it needs to be 12!
  if(str == 1)
  {
   month = 12;
  }
   //call xml
   xml()
   //send dat query
   xmlhttp.open("GET","redraw.php?month="+encodeURIComponent(month),true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

redraw.php:

```
// draws the calendar 
function draw_calendar($month,$year){
  // table headings 
  $headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
  $calendar= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head" id = "cell" style = "min-width:150px;">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

  // days and weeks vars now 
  $days_last_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month-1,1,$year));
  $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
  $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
  $days_in_this_week = 1;
  $day_counter = 0;
  $dates_array = array();
  $today = date("d");

  // row for week one 
  $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

  // print "blank" days until the first of the current week 
  for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++)
  {
    $calendar.= '<td class = "calendar-day-prev" id = "cell" style = "min-width:150px;"><div class = "day-prev-    number" style = "color:#929D9D">'.(($days_last_month -($running_day - 1)) + $x).'</div>';
    $calendar.= str_repeat('<p>&nbsp;</p>',2);
    $calendar.= '</td>';
    $days_in_this_week++;
  }

  // keep going with days....
  for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++)
  {
   $calendar.= '<td class = "calendar-day" id = "cell" style = "  min-width:150px;"';
  //if the day is today we obviously need to have a differnet style for it... 
    if($list_day == $today)
    {
     $calendar.= ' style = "background-color:#9494B8;font-weight:bol;">';
    }
    else
    {
     $calendar.= '>';
    }

      // add in the day number 
      $calendar.= '<div class = "day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

      // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO QUERY ENTRIES PER DAY
      $calendar.= str_repeat('<p>&nbsp;</p>',2);

    $calendar.= '</td>';
    if($running_day == 6)
    {
      $calendar.= '</tr>';
      if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month)
      {
        $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
      }
      $running_day = -1;
      $days_in_this_week = 0;
    }
    $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
  }

  // finish the rest of the days in the week 
  if($days_in_this_week < 8 && $days_in_this_week != 1)
  {
    for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++)
    {
      $calendar.= '<td class = "calendar-day-after" id = "cell" style = "  min-width:150px;"><div class = "day-post-number" style = "color:#929D9D;">'.$x.'</div>';
      $calendar.= str_repeat('<p>&nbsp;</p>',2); 
      $calendar.= '</td>';
    }
  };

  // final row 
  $calendar.= '</tr>';

  // all done, return result 
  return $calendar;

}

//draw the calendar
$year = date ('Y');
$month_title = date ('F');

//Sent variables
if(!empty($_REQUEST['month']))
{
  $month_display = $_REQUEST['month'];
}
else
{
  $month_display = date ('n');
}
echo draw_calendar($month_display,$year);
```

heres a good depiction of whats going on:

what it should look like:
[image: start]

on the first click:
[image: onclick]

what is inserted by the js into the `<div id = "calendar">`
[image: kinda works]

what is returned by the php(this part is seemingly correct):
[image: bad]

Comment: Did you try to "redraw" the same month you are in, to see if the same thing happens? I'm curious to know why you don't use jQuery for the ajax calls... would be simpler right?

Comment: So if `#calendar` is a DIV, and your `draw_calendar` returns a bunch of TR's, where's that TABLE supposed to come from?

Comment: @Perroloco not too familiar with jquery to be frank, i have never had much luck with it. but regardless, this still should work. ive also tried it cross browser. And to answer your question, yes, this occurs no matter what

Comment: @robertklep the entire table is drawn with the php script. the ajax even returns it, as shown in the firebug screen capture

Comment: the Firebug output begins with `<tr`, not `<table`

Comment: @JohnDoe, I don't see the <table> tag in firebug neither :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
```

You are inserting table rows into a `div`, not a `table`. Add the missing table tag or append the data into the table.

NITPICKS - You have "header cells" but you do not use th elements. You are not using thead and tbody.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't adding `<table>` tags *anywhere*.

In your php, replace this line:

```
$calendar= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head" id = "cell" style = "min-width:150px;">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';
```

With:

```
$calendar= '<table><tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head" id = "cell" style = "min-width:150px;">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';
```

And this line:

```
return $calendar;
```

With:

```
return $calendar . '</table>';
```